# Why use OL and UL lists for label and input elements in html5 forms?

Tags: html, forms, input, html-lists

The html forms 10 years ago did not use an ul/ol tag and put the labels and inputs inside li-tags.

Why are so so many html5 forms tutorials use this approach when ul/ol tags are so old ??

Where is the advantage using those tags in forms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's because of the semantic meaning of HTML tags.

In real life the form is just an unordered (or ordered) list of inputs. That's why it should be similar in HTML. It makes it easier to understand for search engine crawlers and pages reading apps.

And why it wasn't done this way 10 years ago? Maybe because nobody used to care about things like that.

Answer (score 0):

There are so many ways to sort out elements of a form. Some people use `<dl>` (definition list), some uses `<p>`, some `<div>` and many doesnt use anything but `<label>` and  tags. Everybody can go with what suits them better.
If you want some pro and con about `<li>`, I can come with both. Example of con: you can't have other content between `<li>` just some CSS facility like `content before/after`, but fully supported by all browsers. Example of pro: I can't really think now at nothing but at some special cases of printing with different media print CSS where you could print the list numbers( in case of `<ol>`, bullets, any graphic you set up in stylesheet. And the corect answer it is imho, about (again) CSS and how do you want to style the the form. There is no need in doing it as they describe in those tutorials.